# Prevent partial requests from being handled by other instances

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, load-balancing, autoscaling

[image]

Suppose UI is sending 100k requests to Order Micro-service and order micro-service is auto-scaling itself to handle this traffic.
Suppose instance 1 crashed while handling a few requests i.e. 500 requests at a time.
and those 500 requests are partially processed.
We want those 500 requests not to be processed by any other instances.

**Questions:**

1. How will you handle this scenario?
2. Suppose I have written some job that is running inside Order micro-service, then how I can force to run only one (cron) job at a time irrespective of the number of running instances?
   Also, how to ensure that when auto-scaling happens and some instances are destroyed then that (cron) job is started on any other instance which is currently up and running?

Also, can someone suggest where can I find such design case studies?

Comment: Why does 100k requests matter? The autoscaler doesn't matter... You would have the same question with just 2 requests and 2 instances and 1 crashed while processing one request. Are you actually re-sending requests? Why would the requests be reprocessed elsewhere?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I am not re-sending the requests. All the requests are sent only once from UI and UI then wait for the response for that request. And requests CAN NOT be processed elsewhere because some part of the transaction has been already committed and then the system crashed.

Comment: Okay, so the transaction wouldn't be done elsewhere so there's nothing to do to prevent it unless you block future requests based on the partial information you were able to store before any crash

Answer (score 0):

There's a trivial way to ensure that the requests aren't processed by other instances: never retry a request and move to at-most-once processing.  Guaranteed exactly-once is not possible in the general case (at least not with asynchronous communication networks...).  At-least-once requires a means of signaling that the request has not been successfully processed: if no such response has been received, the requestor retries: this implies that if the response is dropped (or the responder crashes after fully processing the request but before sending the response) the request will be processed (at least) twice.

For the job case, you can follow the broad techniques used in Akka Cluster Singleton: the auto-scaled instances form a cluster among themselves and track the location and liveness of each instance (this also requires the individual instances to determine when they've been partitioned from the others and should shut themselves down).  The job is then run on an instance selected in such a way that every node in the cluster selects the same unique instance (Akka Cluster Singleton chooses the oldest member of the cluster).  When other instances see that the instance chosen for the job has crashed, the new oldest member is chosen (typically after a short delay).